# How to update Android OS on the device through an App

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to update the Android OS through an App(Using Android API or any other API/) after checking if a newer Android version is available in the market/Playstore
The Use Case required to be supported here is as follows:

1. The App starts and checks the version of the installed Android OS
2. It then finds the version of available Android OS in the
       Playstore/other repository for that device
3. Then it compares the two version and if the available version is
   newer, then it installs the new Android version on the device

How can it be implemented , especially the third point ? I do not want to root the device for that, so if there is any way to achieve this, please help ....

Comment: I tried to do something similar once, and as far as I know, it's impossible.

Comment: Updates are driven by device manufacturers not Google. Google just releases the new AOSP code which manufactures use, and tailor to their needs which they use to update their OS and release on their own timeline.

Comment: First, the blog post that you link to indicates that their technique has not worked in quite some time ("While this trick worked fine for a few Android versions, it no longer appears to work reliably. Worse yet, it sometimes causes problems that can only be fixed by removing your Google account from the device and re-adding it. We no longer recommend doing this.") Second, that approach was only for Nexus series devices, which are a tiny percentage of Android devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi i am new to android.I, by mistake pasted the wrong link  .What I need is to update device OS pragmatically. Is it possible??

Comment: @inner_class7 so how does the device updates to new android version ??If manufacturers uses AoSP to release new version how does all of it work?

Comment: "Is it possible?" -- only if you are the device manufacturer, or perhaps if you are the author of the custom ROM (firmware) that is running on the device.

Comment: @CommonsWare and how can i achieve it with firmware? any link or something?

Comment: If you are the author of the firmware, presumably there are recipes available for implementing your own OTA update system. You might see which (if any) of the popular custom firmwares, like CyanogenMod, offer this sort of thing, then see how they do it. Stack Overflow is not an especially good place for questions on implementing an OTA update system -- you might try the xda:developers forums or something.

Comment: @inner_class7 So if user chooses to update I will be downloading the android factory img file.So how do i proceed further with this.I need to write some code to trigger the update with that file?since i cannot use any third party app like TWRP or any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating your android version you would need

- Custom Android on you device.[(Some more info)](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-flash-a-custom-recovery-like-CWM-or-TWRP-on-Android_id53914)
- Rooted device.[why need rooting?](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/misc/what-is-rooting-and-why-should-i-do-it-the-pros-and-cons-of-android-rooting/)

Now for installing we would need to  [flash ROM](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6028/what-is-the-meaning-of-flashing-a-custom-rom).You would also need to have check for version of the OS available, which depend upon your logic .Generally Samsung ,Sony they use custom android and the updates are pushed over app center( or something like that,not much knowledge) in your case it may be any cloud service or server to check version for your custom android.

When we have a new version, after user accepts to upgrade, a new img file would be downloaded to your device which would be used to upgrade the OS.Please note you would also need a [recovery backup method](http://www.android.gs/update-xperia-s-android-4-4-2-kitkat-os-with-pure-aosp-custom-rom-firmware/) too.There are some [Commands](http://schnouki.net/posts/2014/08/13/flashing-a-stock-android-image-without-wiping-user-data/) that can be used to extract and download the OS through your code.

I haven't implemented it yet but this is the procedure i could find.
I hope this would help others.

**UPDATE**

I have got some new information about how can we initiate the update through code. the [Link](http://shriduttkothari.blogspot.in/2013/08/fota-in-android-mechanism.html) and there's this [another link](http://jhshi.me/2013/12/13/how-to-apply-downloaded-ota-package/) that can be great help.
In both the examples they are using [SystemRcovery class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#installPackage%28android.content.Context,%20java.io.File%29) with intallerPackage API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API. If your device has an update feature built in (most do), you can decompile the update service and see how it works. If your device does not have an update feature, then you can look at custom ROMs for your device. Once you get ahold of a ROM or an update.zip you want to use, the process cannot be done *automatically*. The updating takes place in the system recovery mode where the user will have to select the .zip to update. However, if you can decompile and figure out how your manufacturer's update service works, maybe you can pull off an automated process.

There aren't any tutorials or documentation for this, as it is 100% dependent on phone model/OS. You can probably find a flashable ROM for your device, however, but the process is rarely automated. Actually, take a look at [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en) in this case, it is a somewhat automated upgrade app. I tried it before and it bricked my phone. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know where to ask if there is a newer version. And then is there an upgrade available for that particular device. At that point you could broadcast a request to update. Does not the device know when an update is available?